# Powershell - Rolling script to change AD user expiration dates

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to write a script for on-the-fly AD account expiration date amendments. The script I've written below mostly works, but does not quite work the way I want it to (I'm a bit of a Powershell noob).

I've made a rolling script that asks for a username, then a new expiry date, then shows what the date has been changed to, then starts again. The problem is, that if I enter 05/07/2021, for example, it sets the expiration date in AD to midnight on 04/07/2021, but the script reports the date changed to 05/07/2021. Ideally, I want this to change it to midnight on 05/07/2021, but have the script report the changed date to 05/07/2021, not 06/07/2021.

I had the idea of rolling the input date forward 24 hours by doing this:

```
[datetime]$AD_User_date = Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY"
$AD_User_date_2 = $AD_User_date.AddHours(24)

Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $AD_User -DateTime $AD_User_date_2
```

But this changes the date format to US, so inputting 05/07/2021 changes the account expiration date changes to 07/05/2021. Which is a bummer.

The code I have so far is super basic, I'm probably missing an obvious way of doing this, please have a look and let me know where I've gone wrong:

```
Clear-Host

$continue = $true

while ($continue){

write-host "AD Account Date Changer"

$AD_User = Read-Host "Enter username"

$AD_User = $AD_User.Trim()

$AD_User_date = Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY"

Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $AD_User -DateTime $AD_User_date

$AD_User_date_collect = Get-ADUser -Identity $AD_User -Properties AccountExpirationDate | select -ExpandProperty AccountExpirationDate

$AD_User_date_collect_2 = $AD_User_date_collect.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

Write-Host "New account expiration date is $AD_User_date_collect_2"

Write-Host ""

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `$AD_User_date = Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY" ; 
$AD_User_date_2 = ([datetime]::ParseExact($AD_User_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null)).AddHours(24)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have the problem you think you have.

If you do:

```
Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $AD_User -DateTime '05/07/2021'
```

then

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $AD_User -Properties AccountExpirationDate
```

The expiration date will show as 05/07/2021 00:00:00, i.e the very start of the day of the 5th. If you look in AD Users and Computers it will show 04/07/2021, however the caption clearly shows ***"End of:"***, to make it clear that the account will be active throughout the day of the 4th:

[image]

All of that said, here is your script with a bit of date validation:

```
Clear-Host
$continue = $true

while ($continue){
    write-host "AD Account Date Changer"
    $AD_User = Read-Host "Enter username"

    $AD_User = $AD_User.Trim()

    $AD_User_date = new-object datetime
    do{
     $Entered_Date= Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY"
     $result = [datetime]::tryparseexact($Entered_Date,'dd/MM/yyyy',[cultureinfo]("en-GB"), [globalization.datetimestyles]("None"),[ref]$AD_User_date)
     if(!$result){write-host 'Invalid date entered!'}
    }until($result)


    try{
        Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $AD_User -DateTime $AD_User_date.AddHours(24)
        Write-Host "New account expiration date is the end of $(($AD_User_date).toString('dd/MM/yyyy'))"
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Unable to set account expiry: $_"
    }
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Comment: `$input` is an automatic variable in PowerShell. Ypu should not use it as self defined variable name.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it use a name in OPs style.

Comment: Amazing job Tom! Tried this today and it works great! I promise when my colleagues ask I'll give you credit.