# Powershell script to bulk extend AD account expiration dates from CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking for help creating a script that requests the user input a date, then imports AD usernames from a CSV file that is in the same folder as the script then extends the expiration dates of all account usernames listed in the CSV, to the date entered, then reports success and/or failure.

So far the script below does most of this. I adapted it from a script Tom helped me with here - [Powershell - Rolling script to change AD user expiration dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566785/powershell-rolling-script-to-change-ad-user-expiration-dates/68567693#68567693).

I've been trying to add additional functionality to the script below. I'm trying to get it so that the script will continue past blank and bad entries on the CSV and, more importantly, display these bad entries on the screen, so the user can see which entries failed.

The script will continue past bad entries if the `try{` and `}catch{` is removed and `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` is put at the top of the script, but the script still stops at blank entries and doesn't inform the user of failed entries.

Ideally I would like the script to say something like **"failed to modify account for user_a"** when it runs across an entry that it doesn't find in AD; like a typo or an account that's been deleted.

I had the idea that perhaps I could run the contents of the CSV through AD first with something like:

```
(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.user).DnsHostName
If ($null -eq $_.user)
```

and then have the script push all the ones that weren't `$null` through the rest of the script and then spit out the ones ones that were not found in AD on the screen as failed, with the exceptions of the cells in the CSV that were blank, which could probably be done by running an initial `$null` check on the CSV contents.

I cannot figure out how to implement this though. I feel like it is possible. I've tried many iterations of this script, without success.

I was hoping that someone fancies the challenge.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
write-host "Bulk AD Account Expiration Date Changer" 
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Please add the usernames requiring account expiration date extensions to the bulk_accounts_extension.csv file"
Write-Host "and ensure that the bulk_accounts_extension.csv is in the same location as this script."
Write-Host ""

    $AD_User_date = new-object datetime
    do{
    $Entered_Date = Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY"
    $result = [datetime]::tryparseexact($Entered_Date,'dd/MM/yyyy',[cultureinfo]("en-GB"), [globalization.datetimestyles]("None"),[ref]$AD_User_date)
    if(!$result){write-host 'Invalid date entered!'}
    }until($result)
    try{

    Import-Csv ".\bulk_accounts_extension.csv" | foreach-object {Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity ($_.users = $_.users.Trim()) -DateTime $AD_User_date.AddHours(24)}

    Write-Host "New expiration date for all users is the end of $(($AD_User_date).toString('dd/MM/yyyy'))"
    }catch{
    Write-Host "Unable to set account expiry: $_"

    }

pause
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much changed, just a few improvements and what you asked:

> "*Ideally I would like the script to say something like **failed to modify account for user_a** when it runs across an entry that it doesn't find in AD; like a typo or an account that's been deleted.*"

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' # 'Continue' => NO BAD :(
$csvPath = "$PSScriptRoot\bulk_accounts_extension.csv"
$status = [System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]::new()

if(-not(Test-Path $csvPath))
{
    Write-Warning "bulk_accounts_extension.csv could not be found on $PSScriptRoot"
    Read-Host
    break
}

# Set minimum entered date here, must be above 30 days???
$dateMin = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(30)

@'
Bulk AD Account Expiration Date Changer
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Please add the usernames requiring account expiration date extensions
to the bulk_accounts_extension.csv file and ensure that the
bulk_accounts_extension.csv is in the same location as this script.

---------------------------------------------------------------------
'@ | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green

while($true)
{
    try
    {
        # Loop until a valid Date is entered and that Date is above $dateMin

        $Entered_Date = [datetime]::ParseExact(
            (Read-Host "Enter a new expiry date, in the format DD/MM/YYYY"),
            'dd/MM/yyyy',
            [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::new('en-GB')
        )

        if($Entered_Date -lt $dateMin)
        {
            throw
        }

        break
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Invalid date entered! Format must be DD/MM/YYYY and higher than $dateMin"
    }
}

$users = Import-Csv $csvPath

foreach($user in $users.users)
{
    try
    {
        $user = $user.Trim()
        Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $user -DateTime $Entered_Date.AddHours(24)

        $status.Add(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Time = [datetime]::Now
            User = $user
            Status = 'SUCCESS'
            Message = 'New Expiration Date: {0}' -f $Entered_Date.ToShortDateString()
        })
    }
    catch
    {
        # If Set-ADAccountExpiration throws, either because of lack of permissions or can't find
        # the account, this will output something like:
       
        # User          Error         
        # ----          -----         
        # ExampleUser01 User not found
        # ExampleUser02 User not found
        # ExampleUser03 Access Denied 
        # ExampleUser04 User not found
        
        $status.Add(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Time = [datetime]::Now
            User = $user
            Status = 'FAILED'
            Message = $_.Exception.Message
        })
    }
}


$success, $failed = $status.Where({$_.Status -eq 'SUCCESS'},'Split')

$success | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green
$failed | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
```

Comment: Hi. This amazing! I never even thought to add a $dateMin, but you're right, its totally necessary as users would run a risk of pre-dating by accident. Especially just after new years, when they're not used to it yet! Just one more thing, if I may, is it possible to colourise the output? IE white for input requests, green for positive output messages, yellow for warnings, red for errors? I'm used to write-hosts where its easy. Can you even colour hash Tables?

Comment: @VihaanReyansh Warnings are already colored, I added colors for success and error.

Comment: I have given it a test. I think 

`foreach($user in $users.users)
    try`

needs to be: 

`foreach($user in $users.users)
{
    try`

Also the script seems to die on the CSV warning when there`s no CSV in the same folder.

Comment: @VihaanReyansh woops yes, a `{` was missing after I edited the answer, already fixed. Isn't that intended tho? Shouldn't the script finish if there is no CSV found?

Comment: I would like the script to stay on the screen with the message to show the user where they have gone wrong.

Also, is there any way of separating the successes and fails so that successes get displayed in a list before the list of fails? instead of them being intermingled?

Comment: @VihaanReyansh add `Read-Host` so the window doesn't close until they press a key or press the `X`

Comment: That worked great! So is it possible to separate the successes and fails so that successes get displayed in a list before the list of fails? instead of them being intermingled?

Comment: @VihaanReyansh see my last edit. All results are stored in a collection list which you can then use to export to CSV. If the answer was helpful please consider accepting it.

Comment: `Time                User             Status Message                                                                        
----                ----             ------ -------                                                                        
31/07/2021 16:47:03 @{Users=usertest1}  FAILED Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject...
31/07/2021 16:47:03 @{Users=usertest66}   FAILED Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject...`

Comment: `31/07/2021 16:47:03 @{Users=usertest3 } FAILED Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject...`

Comment: Unfortunately, they all seemed to fail, usertest66 is the one that should have failed, I had a space before usertest1 that does look like it got trimmed, but there seems to be a space after usertest3 in the error message that looks to have not been trimmed, which I thought was odd.

Comment: @VihaanReyansh edited, changed `$users` for `$users.users`

Comment: Absolutely amazing job! `Message = 'New Expiration Date: {0}' -f $Entered_Date.AddHours(24).ToShortDateString()` needs to be `Message = New Expiration Date: {0}' -f $Entered_Date.ToShortDateString()` as it was reporting the date change +24 hours, aside from that you absolutely nailed it!

Comment: @VihaanReyansh you have `-DateTime $AD_User_date.AddHours(24)` on your script hence why I added that.

Comment: Yes, it belongs here: `Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $user -DateTime $Entered_Date.AddHours(24)` where it's taking the date the user input and adding 24 hours, so that in AD the expiration date is on the say they entered and not the end of the day before. but here `Message = 'New Expiration Date: {0}' -f $Entered_Date.AddHours(24).ToShortDateString()` it's adding 24 hours to what the user input and displaying it as the changed date.

Comment: Also, is there any way to get the warning for $datemin to be in dd/mm/yyyy GB format?

Comment: Actually I think I've figured it out: 
`$dateMin = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(30)` 
`$dateMin_short = $dateMin.ToShortDateString()` 
`Write-Warning "Invalid date entered! Format must be DD/MM/YYYY and higher than $dateMin_short"` 
Thanks for all you help!